# Cannot assign value of type 'Date?' to type 'String?' Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

[//error: Cannot assign value of type 'Date?' to type 'String?'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4kS1.png)

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: match.dateTimeGMT)
print("date: \(date!)")
cell.dateTimeGMTLabel.text = date
```

> Error: Cannot assign value of type 'Date?' to type 'String?'

Comment: write like this: cell.dateTimeGMTLabel.text = " \ (date)", or convert your date to sting

Comment: is `match.dateTimeGMT` a `Date` or `String` object?

Comment: match.dateTimeGMT is a String Object

Comment: I tried string interploation but won't worked.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? You already have a String Date representation, are you trying to convert that to another String representation to present to the user? If so, why are you assigning a `Date` object to your label's `text` property instead of using the `DateFormatter` to convert your `Date` to the format you actually need?

Comment: i am trying to display date on my label. how can i display that.

Comment: Why are you converting a `String` to a `Date` if you want to set the label to the date? Surely you could just use `cell.dateTimeGMTLabel.text = match.dateTimeGMT`

Comment: but dateTimeGMT is in this format - 2018-05-27T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: And what format are you trying to display? Since your current code won't convert your `dateTimeGMT` to a different format, it simply tries to display that in the exact same format...

Comment: i am trying to removing that T and Z and display in 2018-05-27 00:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question properly now. You would need to re-create a string from the date using a new format, like so:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

// Change the `...` for your needs
guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-05-27T00:00:00.000Z") else { ... }

// Changing the format accordingly or use `DateFormatter.Style`
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
cell.dateTimeGMTLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: yes. i want to recreate a string from the date using new format .

Comment: You should change the `...` to suit your needs, either by calling `return`, or `fatalError()`, or just throwing a custom error. See [here](https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/) for guard statement uses.

Comment: i used inside else a print statement and return but still shows an error that non-void function should return a value.

Comment: the date is displaying in formatted manner in console but when i tried to display it on my label its not working.